# Share mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently switched from ext/mysql to mysqli in a PHP project. In that project, I extensively used the connection reuse feature of [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) by setting the `new_link` parameter set to `false`.

As far as I understand, there is no such mechanism in `mysqli_connect`; it will always return a new connection even though the same host and user is used. Is this correct? Is there some other function that can mimic the reuse-behaviour?

NB: I see that with prepending the host with `p:` will create a persistent connection. However, this cannot be used in my case, as part of my project relies on temporary tables.

*Update:*
The actual mysqli object is embedded in a DB handler class which manages access to the database. This handler is always used to interact with the DB.

I oversimplified my problem because I just wanted to focus on the question if mysqli can automatically reuse a single connection by multiple calls to `mysqli_connect` with identical parameters. My project is an extenstion to a framework and provides multiple entry points and hooks. I cannot control the order or number of function calles from the hosting framework into my extension. Each part of my extension creates an instance of the DB handler, but could reuse the actual underlying connection.

The creation of the DB handler is done though a db-factory. So I will probabely have to implement some sort of connection-caching there myself...

Comment: Shouldn't the persistent connection keep that as it will keep the pool for reuse? `The idea behind persistent connections is that a connection between a client process and a database can be reused by a client process, rather than being created and destroyed multiple times.`

Comment: I thought that using persistent connections could cause problems with temp. tables, and as I cannot control the server configuration, I would rather not use this feature. However, I still don't know if opening a persistent connection from the same script multiple times would always return the same connection, *without closing the connections*

Comment: Well, I don't know and cannot control the hosting environments... and with all the discussions about *possible* problems with persistent connections under *some* conditions, I better back off ;)

Comment: What I meant to say is that you can easily test it by making a simple application using it to see how it behaves, which is "trial and error".

Comment: I tested it, `mysqli_connect` always returns a new connection, even when using the same non-persistent parameters. So I will build my own cache...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, mysqli ext doesn't follow that lazy mysql ext behavior, and for a reason.
So, you have to always explicitly address mysqli object. The only problem, though, is with variable scope. But as long as you have `$mysqli` object visible, you can use it all right.

However, there is another problem: you shouldn't address `$mysqli` object in your application code at all. That was a problem with old mysql ext and it is a problem with mysqli ext as well - **it is not intended to be used in the application code as is.**

One have to create a some sort of **wrapper**, to encapsulate all the database related stuff, and in the application code always use this wrapper class only.

So, get yourself such a wrapper, create an instance of it, and then pass into every class and function as a parameter.

Comment: I oversimplified... I do use a wrapper, and a factory for creating it! Check my update

Comment: then it should be no problem at all